# htaccess redirect rule parameters

Tags: .htaccess

Did a few searches on SO but couldn't find the right answer.

I want to redirect

?q=string+string1&p=2&s= (domain.com/?q=string...)

to

/category/name (domain.com/categ...)

That link is showing up in Google Analytics and is giving an 404 since i have migrated my site to WordPress. The parameters are not needed any more and must be deleted in the request.

How can I archive that?

This is not working:
RewriteRule ^/?q=string+string1&p=2&s= /category/name/? [R=301,L,QSD]

Comment: Sorry, but from your questionit is not really clear what you catually want to redirect to what.

Comment: @arkascha changed my question a little bit, I hope it is clear now.